# Ruby from the command line - sticking - Windows

Tags: ruby, command-line, rails-console

I have seen this behavior on Windows with Ruby for a long time. If I install a gem sometimes the command line will just get "lost" and stop printing output until you go back to the command line and hit enter a few times.

I notice this in other places too. Like starting up a Ruby on Rails console. Or generating a model with Rails.

Have other people seen this? What causes this?
The weird thing is this doesn't happen all the time.

I have never seen this with PHP, Lua, Perl or Python from the command line.

I have seen this on Vista and Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit). This happens on multiple machines.

Comment: Any versions, SP levels etc you can tell us about? I don't think I've ever seen this, but we may be on very different Windows/Ruby setups.

Comment: I have seen this on Vista and Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit). This happens on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to copy any text from the command window before this happened? The Windows console gets locked if the select mode is ON (i.e. if you selected some text in the console and switched the window)

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8131/consolez.gif](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8131/consolez.gif)

Comment: I was not copying and pasting this last time. Cutting and pasting doesn't seem to be a factor in the issue.

Comment: I have seen such behavior in Quick Edit mode.

Comment: weird. should I grab some replacement console?

Comment: So is the problem because of Quick Edit?